# Proper term for waveform correction -- demodulation or undistortion

Tags: demodulation

I have a measured a periodic signal waveform \$v(t)\$ that can be modeled as:

\$v(t) = f(\phi) A \sin(2\pi ft + \psi)\$

where \$A\$ is a constant amplitude, \$f\$ is signal frequency, \$t\$ is time and \$\psi\$ is a constant phase.

Let say \$f(\phi)\$ is \$ f = k \cos(\phi)\$, where \$k\$ is a constant and \$\phi\$ is a function of time \$t\$.

Now I can *correct* the signal \$v(t)\$ by removing the dependency to \$
\phi\$ factor i.e. \$v'(t)\$ = \$v(t)/f(\phi)\$.

My question: is the process getting \$v'(t)\$ from \$v(t)\$ considered signal waveform demodulation ? or undistortion ?

The generic term I can think safely would be signal waveform correction but it would be better if there is a precise terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe () you have a waveform that is amplitude modulated, where () is your modulating signal. Typically, what we call *demodulation* is the process of recovering () as opposed to obtaining ′() = ()/().
You seem to be willing to remove the effects of () in you signal, what makes me believe that there is no information in () you want to recover. It seems you simply want to clean the signal to look more like a sine wave. If this is the case, then the way you name this process may vary depending on what you are trying to accomplish. Words like *amplitude modulation removal* or *carrier recovery* or *clock recovery* come to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

A measured signal - you must estimate some of the parameters and the amplitude function. You have essentially done demodulation and carrier reconstruction for a signal which is assumed to have linear modulation (DSB in this case)